# WordPress get_header return something else

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I am new in WordPress and I have problem with creating WordPress theme.

I've created a simple template (my first template), in the tutorial I read that I should cut all the header content and paste it in the `header.php` file.

I did this, and pasted all the header from `<!Doctype html>` to `</head>` in `header.php` and when I include header using `get_header()` WordPress add a link inside a `<div id="header" role="banner">` in body and show that to me.

I don't need that link and div, How to get the rid of that?

This is my code:

**index.php:**

```
<?php
get_header();
?>


<div id="extra-content">
    <div id="extra-left-div">
        <h3>Posts</h3>
        <?php if(have_posts()): ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ):the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
    <div id="extra-tag-div">
        <h3>Tags</h3>
        <?php the_tags('',''); ?> 
    </div>
    <div id="extra-category-div">
        <h3>Categories</h3>
    <?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&hierarchical=0&depth=1&title_li=');?>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="full-div">
<div id="logo">
    <h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
</div>



<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
 <ul id="main-content">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<li class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h2 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
 <div class="summery-d"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

  <div class="post-meta">
    <time> <?php the_date(); ?></time>
</div>
</li>




<?php endwhile; ?>
 </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/first.js"></script>

<title><?php

global $page, $paged;

wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

bloginfo( 'name' );

$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );

if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )

echo " | $site_description";

if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )

echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'mytheme' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />
<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>

<link rel="alternate" type="appliction/rss+xml" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" title="<?php printf(__( 'آخرین مطالب %s', 'mytheme' ), wp_specialchars( get_bloginfo('name'), 1 ) ); ?>" />

<link rel="alternate" type="appliction/rss+xml" href="<?php bloginfo('comments_rss2_url'); ?>" title="<?php printf(__( 'آخرین نظرات %s', 'mytheme' ), wp_specialchars( get_bloginfo('name'), 1 ) ); ?>" />

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" /> 

</head>


<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div class="behind" id="b-1">

</div>

<div class="behind" id="b-2">

</div>

<div class="behind" id="b-3">

</div>

<div class="behind" id="b-4">

</div>

<div class="behind" id="b-5">

</div>

<div class="behind" id="b-6">

</div>

<div class="behind" id="b-7">

</div>
<a id="menu-a" href="javascript:void(0);">

</a>
```

divs with `.behind` class and `#menu-a` and some other elements are not in the source (just press ctrl+u), and a link added that I don't need it

```
<div id="header" role="banner">
    <div id="headerimg">
        <h1><a href="http://balit.ir/blog/">Mohammad Kermani</a></h1>
        <div class="description"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
```

I am working on [this website](http://www.balit.ir/blog)

Answer (score 0):

I found the **answer**

There is not problem, I was named the `header.php` as `headr.php`

I just post this answer because maybe one other person has same problem...